# Executing Jasmine tests for frontend theme's

Tags: magento2, javascript, unit-tests

I can't get some of the Jasmine tests for the frontend (blank and luma themes) to work.

I have generated the static files as described in the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/test/js/jasmine.html).

```
$ bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

I can e.g. run:

```
$ grunt spec:blank --file="dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Ui/base/js/grid/columns/actions.test.js"

[...]
ui/js/grid/columns/actions
   ✓ Check getVisibleActions function
   ✓ Check addAction function
   ✓ Check isSingle and isMultiple function
   ✓ Check isActionVisible function
   ✓ Check updateActions function
   ✓ Check applyAction function
   ✓ Check getAction function

7 specs in 0.066s.
>> 0 failures

Done.
[...]
```

But e.g. the following two do not work:

```
$ grunt spec:blank --file="dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/sidebar.test.js"

[...]
 Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar
   Check remove mini-cart item callback.
     X Cart item is exists
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shoppingCartUrl' of undefined thrown (1)
>> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shoppingCartUrl' of undefined thrown null
       TypeError: Cannot read property '_removeItemAfter' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_removeItemAfter' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/sidebar.test.js:67:25)
>>     at <Jasmine>
     X Cart item doesn't exists
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot read property '_removeItemAfter' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_removeItemAfter' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/sidebar.test.js:77:25)
>>     at <Jasmine>
     X Method "_removeItemAfter" is defined
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot read property '_removeItemAfter' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_removeItemAfter' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/sidebar.test.js:61:32)
>>     at <Jasmine>
   Check update item quantity callback.
     X Cart item is exists
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for _hideItemButton()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) (2)
>> Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for _hideItemButton()
>> Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for _hideItemButton()
>> Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
>>     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/sidebar.test.js:95:17)
>>     at <Jasmine>
     X Cart item doesn't exists
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for _hideItemButton()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) (2)
>> Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for _hideItemButton()
>> Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for _hideItemButton()
>> Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
>>     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/sidebar.test.js:106:17)
>>     at <Jasmine>
     X Method "_updateItemQtyAfter" is defined
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot read property '_updateItemQtyAfter' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot read property '_updateItemQtyAfter' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/sidebar.test.js:89:32)
>>     at <Jasmine>

6 specs in 25.22s.
>> 6 failures
Warning: Task "jasmine:blank" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

[...]
```

```
$ grunt spec:blank --file="dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js"

[...]
 Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping
   "showFormPopUp" method
     X Check method call.
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined thrown (1)
>> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined thrown null
       TypeError: Cannot read property 'showFormPopUp' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'showFormPopUp' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:124:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>
   "selectShippingMethod" method
     X Check method call.
       Uncaught TypeError: $.mage.__ is not a function thrown (1)
>> Uncaught TypeError: $.mage.__ is not a function thrown null
       TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectShippingMethod' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectShippingMethod' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:162:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>
   "triggerShippingDataValidateEvent" method
     X Check method call.
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:224:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>
   "setShippingInformation" method
     X Check method call.
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for validateShippingInformation()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) (2)
>> Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for validateShippingInformation()
>> Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>) Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for validateShippingInformation()
>> Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
>>     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:170:17)
>>     at <Jasmine>
   "navigate" method
     X Check for return value.
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:105:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>
   "saveNewAddress" method
     X Check method call with valid form data.
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:143:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>
     X Check method call with invalid form data.
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:132:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>
   "validateShippingInformation" method
     X Check method call on positive case.
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:208:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>
     X Check method call on negative cases.
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:190:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>
   "getPopUp" method
     X Check for return value.
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPopUp' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPopUp' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:112:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>
     X Check on single modal call
       Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) (1)
>> Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
>>     at <Jasmine>
       TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPopUp' of undefined (2)
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPopUp' of undefined     at <Jasmine>
>>     at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dev/tests/js/jasmine/tests/app/code/Magento/Checkout/frontend/js/view/shipping.test.js:117:28)
>>     at <Jasmine>

11 specs in 45.333s.
>> 11 failures
Warning: Task "jasmine:blank" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
[...]
```

Are these tests broken? 
Do I miss something?
How can I get all frontend tests to work?

It's the first time I've tried testing with Jasmine in Magento 2 at all, so I appreciate any help and advice!